# How to convert emoticons within text with RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

The following regex works in all but one case.

If I start a text with ":-)" the emoticon should be converted and it is not. What do i have to add to make this possible?

```
    // :-O :O :-o :o

    _message = _message.replace(/\s:-?[Oo]\s/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-freaked-mini"></i>');

    // :-) :)

    _message = _message.replace(/\s:-?\)\s/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-smile-mini"></i>');

    // :-D :D

    _message = _message.replace(/\s:-?D\s/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-laugh-mini"></i>');

    // :-( :(

    _message = _message.replace(/\s:-?\(\s/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-sad-mini"></i>');

    // ;-) ;)

    _message = _message.replace(/\s;-?\)\s/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-wink-mini"></i>');

    // :-/ :/ :-| :|      excluded: :-// ://  (URLs)

    _message = _message.replace(/\s:-?[\/\|](?!\/)\s/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-well-mini"></i>');
```

Comment: I think what @Hacketo is asking is why not use straight up comparison? Replace all ":-)" with the appropriate `<img>` element.

Comment: I guess you could remove all the `\s`. Yes but I was missing that there is multiple cases for one emoticon

Comment: Hacketo was right, if you want to match only separated by spaces substrings, you need to take in account the string limits. As an aside, isn't it better to put all your patterns in a single pattern with capturing groups and use a callback function as replacement? With this way your string will be parsed only once instead of once per pattern.

Comment: I cannot remove \s because "Hello :-Dirty" would create an icon but this should be only text

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^` to anchor to the start of the string (It has this meaning when it is outside square brackets). So we say `<start of string or following a whitespace character>`

We can also do similar with `$` and anchoring to the end of the string.

```
// :-O :O :-o :o

_message = _message.replace(/(^|\s):-?[Oo](\s|$)/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-freaked-mini"></i>');

// :-) :)

_message = _message.replace(/(^|\s):-?\)(\s|$)/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-smile-mini"></i>');

// :-D :D

_message = _message.replace(/(^|\s):-?D(\s|$)/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-laugh-mini"></i>');

// :-( :(

_message = _message.replace(/(^|\s):-?\((\s|$)/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-sad-mini"></i>');

// ;-) ;)

_message = _message.replace(/(^|\s);-?\)(\s|$)/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-wink-mini"></i>');

// :-/ :/ :-| :|      excluded: :-// ://  (URLs)

_message = _message.replace(/(^|\s):-?[\/\|](?!\/)(\s|$)/g, '<i class="icon-emoji-well-mini"></i>');
```

Additionally, as Casimir says, you can do something like this, taking advantage of the fact that as long as it begins with letter, _, or $, a javascript variable may contain almost any character.

```
_message = "He Loves me :), he loves me not. :(";

var Smiles = {"e:-O": "freaked-mini","e:O": "freaked-mini","e:-)": "smile-mini","e:)": "smile-mini","e:-D": "laugh-mini","e:D": "laugh-mini","e:-(": "laugh-mini","e:(": "laugh-mini","e;-)": "wink-mini","e;)": "wink-mini","e:-\\": "well-mini","e:\\": "well-mini","e:-\|": "well-mini","e:\|": "well-mini"}

_message = _message.replace(/(?:^|\s)(:-?[Oo]|:-?\)|:-?\(|:-?D|s:-?|;-?\)|:-?[\/\|](?!\/))(?=\s|$)/g,function (match,p1) {
        return '<i class="icon-emoji-' + Smiles["e" + p1] + '></i>';
    });

console.log(_message);
```

One problem I encountered, no matter which code styling is that it will not catch an emoticon followed immediately by a punctuation mark and `that makes me sad :(.`.

There's an easy fix though, we'll change `(?=\s|$)` to `(?=\s|$|\.|,|\?|\!)`. `And that makes me happy<i class="icon-emoji-smile-mini></i>.`

```
_message = _message.replace(/(?:^|\s)(:-?[Oo]|:-?\)|:-?\(|:-?D|s:-?|;-?\)|:-?[\/\|](?!\/))(?=\s|$|\.|,|\?|\!)/g,function (match,p1) {
        return '<i class="icon-emoji-' + Smiles["e" + p1] + '></i>';
    });

console.log(_message);
```